# Razorengine unique template name from hashed (sha1) template?

Tags: c#, .net, email, razorengine

I have two entirely separate web (api) services.

One resembles the **business case (bc)** and the other's only concern is **sending** (and building) **e-mails (ms)**.

So basically the BC sends all relevant data to the mail service.

```
BC ===== { Sender, Receipient, Subject, Template, Model } =====> MS
```

The mail service takes the template (razor template) and the model and builds the mail's content. It does the same with the subject which may also be a razor template.

The question now is... in order for razorengine to work properly... I need to specify unique names for my mail templates and I'd prefer not to trust the business case with this task. Because the client may choose a name which is already in use by another client (business case).

My solution right now looks like this:

```
string uniqueTemplateName = sha1(template); // bad idea?
string result = _razorEngineService.RunCompile(template, uniqueTemplateName, null, (object)model);
```

Using `sha1(template)` should do the trick, right? **Are there any drawbacks to this?**

Comment: An answer already pointed you at my article on why this is an abuse of the GetHashCode method. If you are interested in the mathematics of why this does not work for *any* 32 bit hash, regardless of method used, see my article here: http://ericlippert.com/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions/  Briefly: chances are 1% that you will get a collision within the first 9300 inputs, and 50% within the first 77000.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have several problems here depending on your requirements.
Initially it seemed like "clientname/templatename" would be a fit.
Usually you just use the path where the template came from (full directory path, database id).

Any kind of hash completely defeats the purpose of the caching layer for you to be able to notice when you need to recycle the current AppDomain because of stale templates. The default CachingProvider will always use the cached entry and changes will be ignored (no recompiles). But you can customize that to your needs. For example you could implement a strategy like: If a single template is edited more than 10 times the AppDomain is recycled. One can achieve this by implementing an `ITemplateManager` and an `ICachingProvider` and some AppDomain recycle code. How to do that is a bit out of scope for the question you asked, but you can look at the existing implementations.

This AppDomain recycle stuff is hard and defeating it with a hash seems like an easy solution, but if you have the requirement of changing template you need to think about it, because we can't abstract that away from you (because loaded assemblies cannot be unloaded). And depending on your users and your environment you might get into a situation where users can start a DOS attack to your service by filling up your memory. If you are fine with the performance you can look at the isolation API as well. With isolation you can use very simple approach like recycle the AppDomain every 1000 compiles (you still need to implement the notification yourself with a custom `ICachingProvider` or even simpler just count the number of times you are using `RunCompile`).

TL;DR Drawbacks:

- Collisions (see the comment of Eric Lippert)
- Unable to find/notice stale templates
- -> DOS situations

Hope this helps,

matthid (Disclosure: A RazorEngine Contributor)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response. It's my understanding as long as the template does not change (unique hash) there won't be compiled anything. Now assuming the templates (~100) cannot be edited by some end user (they need to be deployed by an administrator) I'm on the safe side, right? It's only the model that changes every request...

Comment: Pretty much correct. You should restart the application when an administrator changes the templates (if it happens often), otherwise my post still holds (the user is the administrator in that case). IMHO using the hash (or the template content itself) is completely defeating the purpose of the caching layer (which might or might not be what you want, in your situation you might get away with it. Or  it will come back sooner or later when the requirements change :) ).